# Class type and NSObject type

Tags: objective-c, nsobject

I am trying to understand `Class` type in Objective-C. May I ask what is the different between Class type and NSObject type? It sounds like Class type does something similar like `NSObject` correct?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this has been asked several times... but I couldn't find any old instance, so anyway.

Unlike C++-like languages, classes are actual regular object instances in OBJC.
When you call `[NSObject class]`, it returns a live object which contains class methods and extra informations. These are synthesized by compiler, and this actually provides all the class related features.

`Class` is the type for for these class objects.

One more thing. Because the `Class` objects are objects, they also have class object, and these are called meta-class. See here for more details: 
http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/01/what-is-meta-class-in-objective-c.html

Also, you may be confused because most of types in Cocoa are using `NSObject` as a root class. But it is just a convention, and actually a class doesn't have to subclass `NSObject`.

Answer (score 1):

No `NSObject` is not the same as `Class`.

In Objective C, classes are objects. A class like `NSObject` in an instance the `Class` type. It is correct to say `NSObject` is of type `Class`, just like you would say an instance of `NSObject` is of type `NSObject`.

`Class` is a an object also, but it's type is the meta-class which really isn't for beginners.

Answer (score 1):

A class is a template, e.g. a human
An object is an instance of a class, e.g. bob the human

an NSObject is the root class of most Objective-C classes (e.g NSTextField, NSButton, etc)
So, NSButton inherits the properties from NSObject, and is also a class (a child class).  If you create a button, that button is now an instance (object), of type NSButton (class), which inherits from: NSControl : NSView : NSResponder : NSObject in that order, descending.

More info:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html